# Get multiple responses from the same call with AXIOS GET

Tags: typescript, axios

I am working with AXIOS GET and I need to get several responses from the same request until said response changes one of its values:

```
axios.get('myUrlApi...')
```

And I get the following response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "status": processing
}
```

but after a few seconds the value of `status` changes to `ready`, so what I need to get is:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "status": ready
}
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: You either call again or you will need to implement something like SignalR, RabbitMQ, STOMP etc

Comment: Could I call it again with `setInterval()` ? Is there a way to stop it with `clearInterval()` and get that last response?

Comment: Well you need to show fully reproducible example. Otherwise is very difficult to assess the situation